# Who doesn't belong to this universe?

Tags: visual, odd-one-out

Can you find who doesn't belong to this universe ?

[image]

Comment: Ak19, you've accepted an answer so I have deleted mine. That doesn't imply that I think my answer was incorrect. Thanks for accepting an answer.

Comment: Rob, I didn't say that your answer is incorrect. Your answer contained **methane** but it didn't explain why the others belong and methane or ammonia doesn't belong. Sorry.

Comment: @RewanDemontay haha :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure this is the answer, but it is certainly a start.

> `((( )))` doesn't belong to this Universe.
>
>  This Universe?  No, I mean "this Universe", if you follow.
>
>  The images all represent a letter in "THIS UNIVERSE".
>  T: titanium, H: halo I: index, S: spheres,
>  U: union, N: Newton, I: iota currency, V: Van Allen belt, E: enter, R: robot, S: silane, E: (solar) eruption?
>
>  The final image `((( )))` seems to fit nowhere.
>
>  Unless it represents the space character between the words in "this Universe".
>
>  I would be tempted to say "Space doesn't belong to this Universe".  That sounds cool.
>  But that doesn't quite fit.  If you understand the last image as "space", then it does belong to "this Universe".
>
>  PS: A little voice in my ear wispers "the molecule is methane and the last symbol is "echo".
>  This means the sequence ends with robot-methane-sun-echo.  And clearly methane is out of sequence.
>
>  The answer: M for methane doesn't belong to "this Universe".

Comment: Huh, what if rot13(vg vf npghnyyl gur fha gung qbrfa'g svg. Gur oenpxrgf pbhyq or "rapybfrq")

Comment: Understood.  I completed the answer.  I wasn't quite happy with "eruption".

Comment: That's it, well done!!!